# Oracle forms in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

Can I embed or attach an oracle forms to asp.net?
I have an oracle forms, I just want to reuse that form so that I won't copy or recode the whole form.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good TechNet article addressing Oracle form to .Net migration, which should answer your questions.  Short answer: no.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463141.aspx